# toggleClass() is not a function, but without it accordion doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I'm working with some old code for an accordion using JavaScript adding new functionality. I've finally got it to where the accordion opens and closes on click and there is only one open at a time. My question is this: There is a line of code (panel.toggleClass("mystyle");) that throws a console error that it is not a function, but when I take it out, the toggle no longer works. I'm perplexed on why this is happening. The CSS for mystyle is display:none;.

```
<button role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="answer<?php echo $i; ?>" class="accordion">
     <h2>Websites</h2><i role="presentation" style="float:right; margin:15px;" class="rt-icon icon-plus-circled"></i>
     <h3>Heading</h3>
     <p>Blurb Goes Here</p>
</button>

<div id="answer" class="panel">

<div>
     <h3>Answer</h3>
     <p>Answer Text</p>
</div>

</div>
```

```
<script>

    var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
    var i;
    
    for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
        acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            
            //toggle i class for plus to minus on click
            jQuery("i", this).toggleClass("icon-plus-circled icon-minus-circled-1 ");
            
            var panel = this.nextElementSibling;

            if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
                // need both to make toggle function
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
                panel.toggleClass("mystyle");
            } else {
                panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
                // Loop over all the panels an close each one
                document.querySelectorAll(".panel").forEach(function(panel){
                    panel.style.maxHeight = null;
                });
            }
            var x = this.getAttribute("aria-expanded");
            if (x === "true") {
                x = "false";
                panel.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                x = "true";
                panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
            this.setAttribute("aria-expanded", x);
            panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
        });
    }

</script>
```

Comment: `toggleClass()` is a jQuery method. `panel` is not a jQuery object.

Comment: Why are you switching between DOM and jQuery so much? If you use jQuery you don't need the `for` loop, you can use `$(".accordion").click(function() ... )`. And then you can use `var panel = $(this).next()` and use jQuery methods on it.

Comment: Thank you both for your help! I have inherited this code from an old site and have been struggling to wrap my head around why they wrote the code this way. I will take the suggestion and convert it to just use jQuery which should solve me problem.